# Equation tag in twoside-mode outer

Tags: equations, tex-core, labels, double-sided

At the moment I thinking about the following think. When I use the `twoside` mode to write a book I want to print the number of the equation outer.

I can modify it manually with these two commands:

```
\makeatletter
\def\LEFTTAG{\tagsleft@true}\def\RIGHTTAG{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
```

This solution is bad.

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multido,lipsum,showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{10}{%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
x+y
\end{align}}
\end{document}
```

How can I modify the default environments to print the tags outer?

**EDIT**
In relation to the answers of Werner and the following code the possibilities doesn't work well:

```
\usepackage{scrextend,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\set@field{%
 \ifthispageodd{\global\tagsleft@false}{\global\tagsleft@true}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Don't; equation numbers are *not* like page numbers.

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean?

Comment: you can redefine the equation environments and then set for every equation an internal  label. Then you can have a reference to `\ifodd\pageref{eqn:label}`

Comment: I mean that equation numbers must go on the same side always. Page numbers can go on the outer side because they are used in a different way, when thumbing through the book for finding a page; equation numbers are looked at by following the text and it's immaterial what page they are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first attempt at solving this, the [`everyshi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) is of great help. In the definition below, a choice between left/right tag is made based on whether the page number is odd/even:

```
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
...
\makeatletter
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}% Test page number
    {\global\tagsleft@true}% Following page will have left-tagged equations
    {\global\tagsleft@false}% Following page will have right-tagged equations
}
\makeatother
```

<strike>There's one minor hiccup.</strike> Whenever typesetting an equation at the bottom of a page that does not entirely fit and has to be broken/flushed to the next, the `\EveryShipout` command is "too late" in modifying the tag location (either left or right). One remedy for this is some manual intervention to make sure the equation is pushed to the next page *after* the page is shipped out (for example, by issuing a manual `\break` or perhaps using the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace)). The latter, perhaps more elegant and automated approach, requires the definition of a new environment (using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)):

```
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
...
\NewEnviron{altalign}{% Alternating tag align \begin{altalign} ... \end{altalign}
  \setbox0=\hbox{% Store contents in box0
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{align*}% Unnumbered align
      \BODY
    \end{align*}\end{minipage}
  }%
  \Needspace{\ht0}% Need exactly height of box0 at the bottom of the page
  \begin{align}
    \BODY% Typeset regular tagged align
  \end{align}
}
```

The use of the `environ` package `\NewEnviron` is essential here, since the body/contents of an environment needs to be captured in order to use it (`\BODY` in this case). In essence, the provided `altalign` environment typesets the contents of the required `align` in an `align*` environment (that is, without equation numbers), embedded in a `minipage` of width `\linewidth`, and stores everything in a box (`box0`). Then, `\Needspace` is issued to either do nothing if there is enough space (`\ht0`) on the page, or `\break` if not. Subsequently, the equations are typeset in the traditional `align` (numbered) environment, this time with the correct addition of `EveryShipout`. The solution works since the `align` environment does not break across pages/columns and can therefore be treated as a single block/box.

[image: Alternating equation numbers based on page number]

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I tried it. Unfortunately this solution isn't enough for me ;-). During my test I tried something like:
`\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\set@field{%
   \ifthispageodd{\global\tagsleft@false}{\global\tagsleft@true}%
}
\makeatother` but with the same result.

Comment: @Marco: I've updated my answer to correct for this unwanted, yet TeX-correct, behaviour. I've also included a description of the solution method.